# Select rows (with multiple strings) in pandas dataframe that contain only a given string

Tags: python, pandas, string-matching

I'm manipulating the [2017 developer survey results](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2017). I want to isolate those rows which contain **only** the string `Python` in the `HaveWorkedLanguage` column.

This what that `df['HaveWorkedLanguage']` column looks like:

```
0                                                 Swift
1                         JavaScript; Python; Ruby; SQL
2                                     Java; PHP; Python
3                                        Python; R; SQL
4                                                   NaN
5                                 JavaScript; PHP; Rust
6                                        Matlab; Python
7        CoffeeScript; Clojure; Elixir; Erlang; Haskell
8                                        C#; JavaScript
9                                    Objective-C; Swift
10                                               R; SQL
11                                                  NaN
12                                         C; C++; Java
13                          Java; JavaScript; Ruby; SQL
14                                     Assembly; C; C++
15                                   JavaScript; VB.NET
16                                           JavaScript
17                     Python; Matlab; Rust; SQL; Swift
18                                               Python
19                                         Perl; Python
20                                                  NaN
21                                  C#; JavaScript; SQL
22                                                 Java
23                                          Python; SQL
24                                                  NaN
25                                          Java; Scala
26         Java; JavaScript; Objective-C; Python; Swift
27                                                  NaN
28                                               Python
29                                                  NaN
...
```

I tried using [pandas.Series.str.match](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.match.html) which should:

> Determine if each string matches a regular expression.

as shown here

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("survey_results_public.csv")
rows_w_Python = df[df['HaveWorkedLanguage'].str.match("Python", na=False)]['HaveWorkedLanguage']
```

The problem is that this selects those rows containing `Python` as a first entry, not those containing **only** `Python`, which resulsts in:

```
3                                        Python; R; SQL
17                     Python; Matlab; Rust; SQL; Swift
18                                               Python
23                                          Python; SQL
28                                               Python
...
```

How can I keep the rows that contain only `Python`?

Comment: maybe `r'Python'` as a regex instead of string 'Python'

Comment: You mean using `r"Python"` instead of `Python` in the above command? Tried it, no change.

Comment: Does "only Python" require regex? `df['HaveWorkedLanguage'] == 'Python'`  should create a boolean filter for that.

Comment: @ayhan I think you nailed it, it was simpler than I thought. Could you turn your comment into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For exact matching, `==` operator should suffice. It doesn't require regex.

`df['HaveWorkedLanguage'] == 'Python'`  returns a boolean filter where the value is exactly 'Python'.

Passing this filter to the DataFrame yields:

```
df[df['HaveWorkedLanguage'] == 'Python']
Out: 
   HaveWorkedLanguage
18             Python
28             Python
```